# CSS SVG animation not working

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to do a line animation with an SVG that I found on Google (Little Man Meditating). 
I imported and exported it using 'SVG-edit' - so I could edit the code. The animation does not work at all - is it something to do with 'shadow-root'?
I saw it said 'shadow-root: closed" on Google inspect. I have no idea what that means as I just started learning about SVGs tonight.

Live link to site: http://benjaminthomasgibbs.co.uk/thirdEye.html

HTML :

```
<svg class="logo" width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <defs>
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 51.674 51.674" y="0px" x="0px" id="svg_2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <g>
    <g>
     <path class="logoAni" fill="#fff" d="m51.378,42.158c-0.974,-1.539 -2.923,-2.291 -4.521,-2.977c-0.736,-0.314 -1.525,-0.547 -2.233,-0.921c-0.795,-0.42 -1.371,-1.366 -1.908,-2.048c-0.94,-1.194 -1.84,-2.42 -2.884,-3.529c-0.667,-0.71 -1.18,-1.443 -1.612,-2.32c-0.748,-1.519 -1.233,-3.172 -1.642,-4.811c-0.147,-0.596 -0.28,-1.196 -0.397,-1.799c-0.031,-0.164 -0.062,-0.329 -0.09,-0.495c-0.002,-0.021 -0.004,-0.031 -0.006,-0.041c-0.031,-0.272 -0.049,-0.547 -0.08,-0.819c-0.203,-1.749 -0.703,-3.386 -1.85,-4.749c-1.055,-1.254 -2.809,-2.561 -4.548,-2.274c-0.067,0.011 -0.12,0.036 -0.163,0.067c-0.264,0.122 -0.492,0.349 -0.702,0.527c-0.417,0.355 -0.843,0.69 -1.313,0.973c-1.519,0.913 -3.25,0.946 -4.907,0.398c-0.606,-0.2 -1.179,-0.484 -1.735,-0.795c-0.317,-0.177 -0.622,-0.373 -0.925,-0.573c-0.217,-0.144 -0.394,-0.304 -0.663,-0.32c-0.918,-0.054 -1.909,0.589 -2.591,1.13c-2.092,1.66 -2.214,4.428 -2.585,6.855c-0.218,1.425 -0.428,2.853 -0.801,4.247c-0.375,1.404 -1.021,2.652 -1.816,3.861c-0.82,1.248 -1.776,2.401 -2.735,3.545c-0.456,0.543 -0.916,1.084 -1.37,1.63c-0.467,0.562 -0.888,1.25 -1.501,1.661c-0.3,0.201 -0.703,0.267 -1.046,0.365c-0.368,0.105 -0.737,0.209 -1.106,0.31c-0.606,0.166 -1.229,0.289 -1.806,0.544c-0.624,0.275 -1.839,0.922 -1.842,1.736c-0.002,0.594 0.518,1.084 1.004,1.338c0.809,0.423 1.794,0.449 2.706,0.402c-0.045,0.933 0.096,1.848 0.572,2.674c0.537,0.932 1.464,1.592 2.387,2.102c2.497,1.381 5.427,1.255 8.183,1.456c1.549,0.112 3.08,0.338 4.634,0.407c1.62,0.072 3.243,0.062 4.862,0.045c3.272,-0.036 6.542,-0.02 9.812,-0.018c1.774,0 3.554,-0.002 5.328,-0.005c0.921,0 1.842,0 2.765,0c0.768,0.003 1.534,0.038 2.293,-0.118c1.191,-0.25 2.166,-1.065 2.791,-2.086c0.479,-0.789 0.605,-1.646 0.672,-2.521c0.168,-0.006 0.314,-0.092 0.344,-0.288c0.029,-0.209 0.033,-0.404 0.023,-0.591c0.715,0.214 1.487,0.303 2.18,0.016c0.416,-0.173 0.728,-0.477 0.953,-0.865c0.293,-0.505 0.164,-0.859 -0.131,-1.326zm-15.293,-18.941c-0.004,-0.022 -0.003,-0.016 0,0l0,0zm14.055,20.438c-0.642,0.219 -1.387,-0.004 -2.021,-0.25c-0.749,-1.441 -2.967,-1.97 -4.607,-2.102c-0.01,-0.008 -0.019,-0.021 -0.028,-0.027c-5.75,-3.775 -10.404,-9.9 -10.927,-16.93c-0.017,-0.203 -0.152,-0.323 -0.309,-0.365c-0.167,-0.06 -0.351,-0.023 -0.436,0.144c-0.021,0.033 -0.035,0.071 -0.045,0.114c0,0 0,0 0,0.001c-0.711,4.433 -0.541,9.032 -0.266,13.499c0.021,0.346 0,0.737 0.078,1.076c0.115,0.493 0.375,0.947 0.695,1.336c0.309,0.375 0.695,0.76 1.166,0.92c0.63,0.213 1.367,0.235 2.025,0.322c1.535,0.203 3.08,0.344 4.623,0.482c0.713,0.062 1.428,0.127 2.142,0.191c0.077,0 0.423,0 0.423,0s-0.346,0 -0.423,0c0.059,0.004 0.116,0.01 0.175,0.016c0.238,0.021 0.604,0.119 0.859,0.052c1.106,0.146 3.392,0.58 4.039,1.724c-0.119,1.249 -0.047,2.467 -0.731,3.588c-0.616,1.008 -1.675,1.602 -2.841,1.689c-0.75,0.057 -1.52,0.007 -2.271,0.007c-0.854,0 -1.711,0 -2.564,0.001c-1.645,0.001 -3.289,0.003 -4.934,0.002c-3.271,-0.002 -6.539,-0.016 -9.809,0.02c-0.745,0.01 -1.49,0.012 -2.234,0.007c-0.874,-0.212 -1.741,-0.565 -2.273,-1.265c-0.411,-0.539 -0.428,-1.265 0.01,-1.791c0.642,-0.773 1.96,-0.955 2.89,-1.103c0.695,-0.11 1.405,-0.175 2.108,-0.19c0.042,0 0.065,-0.022 0.094,-0.041c5.185,0.062 10.786,0.074 11.402,-0.158c1.173,-0.443 -19.553,-1.723 -20.44,0c0,0 2.676,0.062 6.092,0.117c-0.955,0.184 -2.049,0.491 -2.6,1.32c-0.421,0.635 -0.325,1.447 0.099,2.049c0.327,0.463 0.794,0.791 1.315,1.033c-0.442,-0.01 -0.884,-0.014 -1.325,-0.033c-1.544,-0.07 -3.068,-0.3 -4.608,-0.412c-2.466,-0.179 -5.006,-0.088 -7.295,-1.172c-0.904,-0.428 -1.795,-1.033 -2.354,-1.878c-0.345,-0.52 -0.483,-1.108 -0.522,-1.71c0.027,-0.053 0.045,-0.113 0.042,-0.189c-0.044,-1.219 0.771,-2.021 1.837,-2.471c0.419,-0.178 0.861,-0.3 1.305,-0.392c0.233,-0.048 0.375,-0.071 0.519,-0.084c2.585,0.001 5.168,0.004 7.753,0.005c1.178,0 2.768,0.102 3.361,-1.156c0.495,-1.051 0.542,-2.365 0.631,-3.511c0.123,-1.581 0.182,-3.169 0.179,-4.755c-0.004,-2.29 -0.015,-4.867 -0.911,-7.015c-0.148,-0.356 -0.64,-0.404 -0.771,0c-1.028,3.149 -2.196,6.277 -3.947,9.105c-1.711,2.766 -4.042,5.053 -6.932,6.562c-0.004,0.002 -0.007,0.004 -0.011,0.006c-0.009,0.005 -0.017,0.01 -0.026,0.015c-0.028,0.015 -0.043,0.035 -0.065,0.054c-1.453,0.287 -2.934,1.043 -3.491,2.355c-0.938,0.066 -2.04,0.105 -2.843,-0.439c-0.161,-0.107 -0.285,-0.283 -0.345,-0.466c-0.067,-0.2 0.776,-0.704 0.942,-0.804c0.442,-0.266 0.886,-0.396 1.381,-0.529c0.801,-0.214 1.601,-0.433 2.396,-0.669c1.32,-0.392 2.076,-1.751 2.918,-2.752c1.831,-2.176 3.852,-4.386 4.983,-7.032c1.084,-2.537 1.303,-5.417 1.7,-8.121c0.162,-1.099 0.404,-2.173 1.001,-3.124c0.575,-0.916 1.482,-1.624 2.502,-1.973c0.502,-0.172 0.56,-0.075 0.994,0.212c0.523,0.347 1.073,0.652 1.641,0.92c0.91,0.429 1.872,0.714 2.875,0.811c1.374,0.132 2.74,-0.255 3.899,-0.986c0.423,-0.267 0.814,-0.583 1.195,-0.906c0.136,-0.115 0.271,-0.232 0.41,-0.344c-0.035,0.027 0.092,-0.065 0.121,-0.084c0.024,-0.017 0.035,-0.024 0.041,-0.03c0.004,0.001 0.006,0.002 0.021,-0.002c0.998,-0.164 2.218,0.565 2.923,1.203c0.679,0.612 1.255,1.299 1.671,2.114c0.748,1.466 0.721,3.113 1.032,4.69c0.341,1.721 0.802,3.428 1.422,5.07c0.347,0.913 0.749,1.812 1.271,2.638c0.607,0.969 1.481,1.738 2.207,2.617c0.699,0.846 1.351,1.727 2.03,2.586c0.427,0.537 0.853,1.127 1.382,1.57c0.439,0.367 0.982,0.564 1.515,0.761c0.534,0.198 1.049,0.419 1.573,0.644c1.271,0.543 2.612,1.144 3.568,2.173c0.104,0.11 0.523,0.567 0.469,0.729c-0.119,0.343 -0.4,0.595 -0.74,0.711zm-17.926,-16.373c1.322,5.668 5.119,10.574 9.832,13.971c-2.352,-0.215 -4.705,-0.398 -7.047,-0.725c-0.512,-0.07 -1.107,-0.072 -1.554,-0.353c-0.437,-0.274 -0.757,-0.759 -0.978,-1.212c-0.151,-0.309 -0.131,-0.682 -0.151,-1.016c-0.027,-0.412 -0.05,-0.824 -0.072,-1.235c-0.165,-3.113 -0.278,-6.3 -0.03,-9.43zm-13.372,-1.533c0.359,1.391 0.428,2.879 0.476,4.289c0.061,1.793 0.008,3.59 -0.105,5.379c-0.072,1.138 -0.161,2.296 -0.436,3.402c-0.108,0.437 -0.28,0.848 -0.728,1.012c-0.68,0.246 -1.495,0.179 -2.204,0.179c-2.206,-0.001 -4.413,-0.003 -6.62,-0.004c2.4,-1.521 4.366,-3.591 5.902,-6.005c1.622,-2.551 2.745,-5.391 3.715,-8.252z"/>
     <path class="logoAni" fill="#fff" d="m26.606,14.687c2.558,-1.003 4.219,-3.521 4.252,-6.248c0,-0.003 0.002,-0.006 0.002,-0.01c-0.024,-2.223 -1.095,-4.24 -2.897,-5.533c-1.81,-1.299 -4.261,-1.533 -6.316,-0.727c-2.023,0.794 -3.533,2.566 -4.063,4.663c-0.546,2.165 0.094,4.466 1.558,6.122c1.836,2.077 4.904,2.737 7.464,1.733zm-8.184,-7.899c0.604,-2.197 2.506,-3.803 4.716,-4.212c3.596,-0.666 6.884,2.286 6.922,5.853c-0.025,2.308 -1.334,4.352 -3.401,5.369c-2.078,1.023 -4.652,0.617 -6.396,-0.864c-1.768,-1.5 -2.45,-3.93 -1.841,-6.146z"/>
    </g>
   </g>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
   <g/>
  </symbol>
 </defs>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <use x="549.04768" y="493.37139" transform="matrix(0.516705922174416,0,0,0.4822158540875421,-136.7349084633355,-116.16454447570459) " xlink:href="#svg_2" id="svg_3"/>
  <g id="svg_4"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
 .logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 39vh;
    left: 57vw;
 }

.logoAni {
  stroke-dasharray: 2193;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash 3s 1;
  -webkit-animation: dash 3s 1;
  -o-animation: dash 3s 1;
  -moz-animation: dash 3s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {

  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2193;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah it does look like because it's nested in a symbol, the `logoAni` was not getting applied. I stripped it out and cleaned up the SVG and tweaked the styles so you can see the animation. I think the other big thing that was missing was that you need a `stroke` property to be set so I went ahead and set that directly in the SVG.

EDIT: Okay so looking at your comment I wanted to address specifically how you could get from my original to what you wanted.

1) In terms of the size, this is based on the [viewbox for SVGs](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/). It would be good to read on that. I guess what they did in the example is they applied the viewBox to the symbol and then used that but I simply added it to the SVG. For now though I made it so you can just edit the width and height in the `.logo` class in the CSS.

2) You said you want it to be nothing and then fill in with white. So two things with this is that the inital whiteness is because the `fill` is set to `#fff`. I went ahead and added it as a CSS attribute so you can play around. If you set it to transparent you get some of what you want but the path apparently doesn't incorporate the inner part of the person's legs so it doesn't get exactly what you want. You probably will need to define the path yourself.

3) I went ahead and reverted some of the things so it uses the values your example uses but also added some changes. Specifically for animations, you need to use `forwards` so that it knows to stay in place and keep the animation in the final state.

Hope that helps!

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.logoAni {
  fill: white;
  stroke-dasharray: 2193;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2193;
  animation: dash 5s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2193;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 51.674 51.674">
<g>
    <g class="container">
     <path class="logoAni" stroke="#fff" d="m51.378,42.158c-0.974,-1.539 -2.923,-2.291 -4.521,-2.977c-0.736,-0.314 -1.525,-0.547 -2.233,-0.921c-0.795,-0.42 -1.371,-1.366 -1.908,-2.048c-0.94,-1.194 -1.84,-2.42 -2.884,-3.529c-0.667,-0.71 -1.18,-1.443 -1.612,-2.32c-0.748,-1.519 -1.233,-3.172 -1.642,-4.811c-0.147,-0.596 -0.28,-1.196 -0.397,-1.799c-0.031,-0.164 -0.062,-0.329 -0.09,-0.495c-0.002,-0.021 -0.004,-0.031 -0.006,-0.041c-0.031,-0.272 -0.049,-0.547 -0.08,-0.819c-0.203,-1.749 -0.703,-3.386 -1.85,-4.749c-1.055,-1.254 -2.809,-2.561 -4.548,-2.274c-0.067,0.011 -0.12,0.036 -0.163,0.067c-0.264,0.122 -0.492,0.349 -0.702,0.527c-0.417,0.355 -0.843,0.69 -1.313,0.973c-1.519,0.913 -3.25,0.946 -4.907,0.398c-0.606,-0.2 -1.179,-0.484 -1.735,-0.795c-0.317,-0.177 -0.622,-0.373 -0.925,-0.573c-0.217,-0.144 -0.394,-0.304 -0.663,-0.32c-0.918,-0.054 -1.909,0.589 -2.591,1.13c-2.092,1.66 -2.214,4.428 -2.585,6.855c-0.218,1.425 -0.428,2.853 -0.801,4.247c-0.375,1.404 -1.021,2.652 -1.816,3.861c-0.82,1.248 -1.776,2.401 -2.735,3.545c-0.456,0.543 -0.916,1.084 -1.37,1.63c-0.467,0.562 -0.888,1.25 -1.501,1.661c-0.3,0.201 -0.703,0.267 -1.046,0.365c-0.368,0.105 -0.737,0.209 -1.106,0.31c-0.606,0.166 -1.229,0.289 -1.806,0.544c-0.624,0.275 -1.839,0.922 -1.842,1.736c-0.002,0.594 0.518,1.084 1.004,1.338c0.809,0.423 1.794,0.449 2.706,0.402c-0.045,0.933 0.096,1.848 0.572,2.674c0.537,0.932 1.464,1.592 2.387,2.102c2.497,1.381 5.427,1.255 8.183,1.456c1.549,0.112 3.08,0.338 4.634,0.407c1.62,0.072 3.243,0.062 4.862,0.045c3.272,-0.036 6.542,-0.02 9.812,-0.018c1.774,0 3.554,-0.002 5.328,-0.005c0.921,0 1.842,0 2.765,0c0.768,0.003 1.534,0.038 2.293,-0.118c1.191,-0.25 2.166,-1.065 2.791,-2.086c0.479,-0.789 0.605,-1.646 0.672,-2.521c0.168,-0.006 0.314,-0.092 0.344,-0.288c0.029,-0.209 0.033,-0.404 0.023,-0.591c0.715,0.214 1.487,0.303 2.18,0.016c0.416,-0.173 0.728,-0.477 0.953,-0.865c0.293,-0.505 0.164,-0.859 -0.131,-1.326zm-15.293,-18.941c-0.004,-0.022 -0.003,-0.016 0,0l0,0zm14.055,20.438c-0.642,0.219 -1.387,-0.004 -2.021,-0.25c-0.749,-1.441 -2.967,-1.97 -4.607,-2.102c-0.01,-0.008 -0.019,-0.021 -0.028,-0.027c-5.75,-3.775 -10.404,-9.9 -10.927,-16.93c-0.017,-0.203 -0.152,-0.323 -0.309,-0.365c-0.167,-0.06 -0.351,-0.023 -0.436,0.144c-0.021,0.033 -0.035,0.071 -0.045,0.114c0,0 0,0 0,0.001c-0.711,4.433 -0.541,9.032 -0.266,13.499c0.021,0.346 0,0.737 0.078,1.076c0.115,0.493 0.375,0.947 0.695,1.336c0.309,0.375 0.695,0.76 1.166,0.92c0.63,0.213 1.367,0.235 2.025,0.322c1.535,0.203 3.08,0.344 4.623,0.482c0.713,0.062 1.428,0.127 2.142,0.191c0.077,0 0.423,0 0.423,0s-0.346,0 -0.423,0c0.059,0.004 0.116,0.01 0.175,0.016c0.238,0.021 0.604,0.119 0.859,0.052c1.106,0.146 3.392,0.58 4.039,1.724c-0.119,1.249 -0.047,2.467 -0.731,3.588c-0.616,1.008 -1.675,1.602 -2.841,1.689c-0.75,0.057 -1.52,0.007 -2.271,0.007c-0.854,0 -1.711,0 -2.564,0.001c-1.645,0.001 -3.289,0.003 -4.934,0.002c-3.271,-0.002 -6.539,-0.016 -9.809,0.02c-0.745,0.01 -1.49,0.012 -2.234,0.007c-0.874,-0.212 -1.741,-0.565 -2.273,-1.265c-0.411,-0.539 -0.428,-1.265 0.01,-1.791c0.642,-0.773 1.96,-0.955 2.89,-1.103c0.695,-0.11 1.405,-0.175 2.108,-0.19c0.042,0 0.065,-0.022 0.094,-0.041c5.185,0.062 10.786,0.074 11.402,-0.158c1.173,-0.443 -19.553,-1.723 -20.44,0c0,0 2.676,0.062 6.092,0.117c-0.955,0.184 -2.049,0.491 -2.6,1.32c-0.421,0.635 -0.325,1.447 0.099,2.049c0.327,0.463 0.794,0.791 1.315,1.033c-0.442,-0.01 -0.884,-0.014 -1.325,-0.033c-1.544,-0.07 -3.068,-0.3 -4.608,-0.412c-2.466,-0.179 -5.006,-0.088 -7.295,-1.172c-0.904,-0.428 -1.795,-1.033 -2.354,-1.878c-0.345,-0.52 -0.483,-1.108 -0.522,-1.71c0.027,-0.053 0.045,-0.113 0.042,-0.189c-0.044,-1.219 0.771,-2.021 1.837,-2.471c0.419,-0.178 0.861,-0.3 1.305,-0.392c0.233,-0.048 0.375,-0.071 0.519,-0.084c2.585,0.001 5.168,0.004 7.753,0.005c1.178,0 2.768,0.102 3.361,-1.156c0.495,-1.051 0.542,-2.365 0.631,-3.511c0.123,-1.581 0.182,-3.169 0.179,-4.755c-0.004,-2.29 -0.015,-4.867 -0.911,-7.015c-0.148,-0.356 -0.64,-0.404 -0.771,0c-1.028,3.149 -2.196,6.277 -3.947,9.105c-1.711,2.766 -4.042,5.053 -6.932,6.562c-0.004,0.002 -0.007,0.004 -0.011,0.006c-0.009,0.005 -0.017,0.01 -0.026,0.015c-0.028,0.015 -0.043,0.035 -0.065,0.054c-1.453,0.287 -2.934,1.043 -3.491,2.355c-0.938,0.066 -2.04,0.105 -2.843,-0.439c-0.161,-0.107 -0.285,-0.283 -0.345,-0.466c-0.067,-0.2 0.776,-0.704 0.942,-0.804c0.442,-0.266 0.886,-0.396 1.381,-0.529c0.801,-0.214 1.601,-0.433 2.396,-0.669c1.32,-0.392 2.076,-1.751 2.918,-2.752c1.831,-2.176 3.852,-4.386 4.983,-7.032c1.084,-2.537 1.303,-5.417 1.7,-8.121c0.162,-1.099 0.404,-2.173 1.001,-3.124c0.575,-0.916 1.482,-1.624 2.502,-1.973c0.502,-0.172 0.56,-0.075 0.994,0.212c0.523,0.347 1.073,0.652 1.641,0.92c0.91,0.429 1.872,0.714 2.875,0.811c1.374,0.132 2.74,-0.255 3.899,-0.986c0.423,-0.267 0.814,-0.583 1.195,-0.906c0.136,-0.115 0.271,-0.232 0.41,-0.344c-0.035,0.027 0.092,-0.065 0.121,-0.084c0.024,-0.017 0.035,-0.024 0.041,-0.03c0.004,0.001 0.006,0.002 0.021,-0.002c0.998,-0.164 2.218,0.565 2.923,1.203c0.679,0.612 1.255,1.299 1.671,2.114c0.748,1.466 0.721,3.113 1.032,4.69c0.341,1.721 0.802,3.428 1.422,5.07c0.347,0.913 0.749,1.812 1.271,2.638c0.607,0.969 1.481,1.738 2.207,2.617c0.699,0.846 1.351,1.727 2.03,2.586c0.427,0.537 0.853,1.127 1.382,1.57c0.439,0.367 0.982,0.564 1.515,0.761c0.534,0.198 1.049,0.419 1.573,0.644c1.271,0.543 2.612,1.144 3.568,2.173c0.104,0.11 0.523,0.567 0.469,0.729c-0.119,0.343 -0.4,0.595 -0.74,0.711zm-17.926,-16.373c1.322,5.668 5.119,10.574 9.832,13.971c-2.352,-0.215 -4.705,-0.398 -7.047,-0.725c-0.512,-0.07 -1.107,-0.072 -1.554,-0.353c-0.437,-0.274 -0.757,-0.759 -0.978,-1.212c-0.151,-0.309 -0.131,-0.682 -0.151,-1.016c-0.027,-0.412 -0.05,-0.824 -0.072,-1.235c-0.165,-3.113 -0.278,-6.3 -0.03,-9.43zm-13.372,-1.533c0.359,1.391 0.428,2.879 0.476,4.289c0.061,1.793 0.008,3.59 -0.105,5.379c-0.072,1.138 -0.161,2.296 -0.436,3.402c-0.108,0.437 -0.28,0.848 -0.728,1.012c-0.68,0.246 -1.495,0.179 -2.204,0.179c-2.206,-0.001 -4.413,-0.003 -6.62,-0.004c2.4,-1.521 4.366,-3.591 5.902,-6.005c1.622,-2.551 2.745,-5.391 3.715,-8.252z"/>
     <path class="logoAni" stroke="#fff" d="m26.606,14.687c2.558,-1.003 4.219,-3.521 4.252,-6.248c0,-0.003 0.002,-0.006 0.002,-0.01c-0.024,-2.223 -1.095,-4.24 -2.897,-5.533c-1.81,-1.299 -4.261,-1.533 -6.316,-0.727c-2.023,0.794 -3.533,2.566 -4.063,4.663c-0.546,2.165 0.094,4.466 1.558,6.122c1.836,2.077 4.904,2.737 7.464,1.733zm-8.184,-7.899c0.604,-2.197 2.506,-3.803 4.716,-4.212c3.596,-0.666 6.884,2.286 6.922,5.853c-0.025,2.308 -1.334,4.352 -3.401,5.369c-2.078,1.023 -4.652,0.617 -6.396,-0.864c-1.768,-1.5 -2.45,-3.93 -1.841,-6.146z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you but now he's tiny. Also I need him to be invisible when the animation starts - it looks like it's just animating the border or something. Its really confusing.

Comment: @BenjaminGibbs710 I updated my answer and I tried to address some of your questions. but all in all it'd be good to [read a post like this to actually understand what's going on](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)